# MySQL query optimization is driving me nuts! Almost same, but horribly different

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have the following two queries `(*)`, which only differ in the field being restricted in the `WHERE` clause (`name1` vs `name2`):

```
SELECT A.third_id, COUNT(DISTINCT B.fourth_id) AS num
FROM first A
JOIN second B ON A.third_id = B.third_id
WHERE A.name1 LIKE 'term%'

SELECT A.third_id, COUNT(DISTINCT B.fourth_id) AS num
FROM first A
JOIN second B ON A.third_id = B.third_id
WHERE A.name2 LIKE 'term%'
```

Both of the `name` fields have a single-column index on them. There is also an index on both `third_id` columns as well as `fourth_id` (which are all foreign keys into other tables, but it is not relevant here).

According to `EXPLAIN`, the first one behaves like this - which is what I want:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref           | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | range | third_id,name | name     | 767     | NULL          | 3491 | Using where | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | ref   | third_id      | third_id | 4       | db.A.third_id |   16 |             | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
```

The second one does this, which I definitely do *not* want:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+----------+---------+---------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys  | key      | key_len | ref           | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+----------+---------+---------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | ALL  | third_id       | NULL     | NULL    | NULL          | 507539 |             | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | ref  | third_id,name2 | third_id | 4       | db.B.third_id |      1 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+----------+---------+---------------+--------+-------------+
```

What the heck is happening here? How do I make the second one behave properly (i.e. like the first one)?

*`(*)` Actually, I don't. I have a bit more complex queries; I have eliminated extras for this post, and distilled them to the minimal queries that still exhibit the problematic behaviour. Also, names were changed to protect the guilty.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add CREATE TABLE statements to your post.
A real SELECT statement would be helpful too.

1 possible reason is that name2 has a much higher percentage of values starting with "term%".

Try enforcing order of tables in query by using STRAIGHT_JOIN.

```
SELECT A.third_id, COUNT(DISTINCT B.fourth_id) AS num
FROM first A
STRAIGHT_JOIN second B ON A.third_id = B.third_id
WHERE A.name2 LIKE 'term%'
```

Answer (score 1):

How many records is in those tables ? Check cardinality/slectivity in name2 column.

If selectivity is low try Naktibalda "STRAIGHT_JOIN" or hints http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html